# Why is `std::is_constructible_v<int[2], int, int> == false`

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17

Reproducible example:

```
#include <type_traits>
static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<int[2], int, int>, "fails against my expectations");
```

I tested this with clang 5 and gcc 7.

Comment: Why do you expect it to be true? An array does not have a constructor. From [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible): "*If `T` is an object or reference type and the variable definition `T obj(std::declval<Args>()...);` is well-formed, provides the member constant value equal to `true`. **In all other cases, value is `false`**.*" `int obj[2](int, int)` is not well-defined. Dont confuse construction with aggregate initialization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible):

> If T is an object or reference type and the variable definition `T obj(std::declval<Args>()...);` is **well-formed**, provides the member constant value equal to true. In *all other cases*, value is false.

In your example `T obj(std::declval<Args>()...);` is *not* well-formed.

This is because `int[2]` is a plain array, which doesn't have any constructor whatsoever.

As a result, this:

```
int obj[2](int, int);
```

is ill-formed.

Arrays are [aggregates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special), thus aggregate initialization comes into play here, not construction.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to check if a type is constructible with aggregates? Ie, is_aggregate_initializable<int[2], int, int> would be true?

Answer (score 2):

The purpose and definition of `std::is_constructible` is to check if an object of the specified type may be constructed as in:

```
T obj(std::declval<Args>()...);
```

And the above is simply not well-formed for an array. An array doesn't have any constructors, it is an aggregate and should be initialized with aggregate initialization.